Texture issue when I overstretch an object
I was trying to create my own door because I was having the same issue with doors made with archimesh, but I realized that the problem was that the thickness of my object was too small. It looks like the faces of the object move away from each other. I'd like to know if there is a way to fix these without changing the dimensions of my objects.
